# Bash script not finding existing directory

Tags: bash

I am using the standard check if a directory exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "~/.junk" ]; then
    echo "yeet"
```

[ -d "~/.junk" ] evaluates to false, however, when I cd into ~ and type ls -a, .junk is indeed one of the directories.

What could be happening?

I am using Linux Mint Vera

Comment: Who is the user running that script ..  Are you sure that `.junk` exists in `~/` for that user?  Also `-d`  will not work if `.junk` is a symlink.  So a `ls -la` inside `~/` and see if it lists junk as a symlink and not a directory.

Comment: edit your Q to show the `ls -la ~/.junk` output. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use the "~" in 'string' such in this case, the character is not treated as a special character and is interpreted literally, so you should replace by $HOME

And change the param -d to -e

-e  - True if the file exists (regardless of type).

-d  - True if the file is a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
if [ -e "$HOME/.junk" ]; then                                                                                               
    echo "yeet"                                                                                                         
fi
```

Comment: Not that you **can** use `~`, you just have to use it properly: `if [ -e ~/.junk ]` works fine. No need to revert to $HOME. If you are in a context, where quotes are advisable, `~` can be used to, as long as it stays outside the quotes: `~/"$MYDOTFILE"` for instance.